# Paypal Standard Method

Tags: paypal

For my project, I have been integrating PayPal sandbox. I have used the following codes for standard method. But I could not receive the notification call(notify-url) from PayPal. What's wrong?

```
<form id="form1" action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" style="display:none;"  accept-charset="utf-8">
  <input type="hidden" name="business" value="test2_biz@gmail.com" />
  <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_cart" />
  <input type="hidden" name="paymentaction" value="sale" />
  <input type="hidden" name="item_name_1" value="lap" />
  <input type="hidden" name="amount_1" value="1" />
  <input type="hidden" name="quantity_1" value="1" />
  <input type="hidden" name="first_name" value="1" /><!--customer first name -->
  <input type="hidden" name="last_name" value="1" /><!--customer last name -->
  <input type="hidden" name="address1" value="1" /><!--customer address 1 name -->
  <input type="hidden" name="address2" value="1" /><!--customer add2 name -->
  <input type="hidden" name="email" value="dfd@rr.ee" /><!--customer email name -->
  <input type="hidden" name="city" value="1" /><!--customer city name -->
  <input type="hidden" name="state" value="1" /><!--customer state name -->
  <input type="hidden" name="country" value="1" /><!--customer country name -->
  <input type="hidden" name="zip" value="1" /><!--customer zip name -->
  <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD" /><!--currrecy in which payment u need-->
  <input type="hidden" name="upload" value="1" /><!--paypal parameter-->
  <input type="hidden" name="return" value="HOST_NAME/default/index/order-return" />
  <input type="hidden" name="cancel_return" id="cancel_return" value="" />
  <input type="hidden" name="notify_url" id="notify_url" value="HOST_NAME/default/index/notify-url/order/222">
  <input type="submit" value="submit">
  </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

As I wrote you in comments, you should have a proper IPN listener with message validation for PayPal to consider the call to your URL a success. 
Here is a rough example of a basic listener:

```
    <?php

    function validateIpnMessage() {
        $ch = curl_init('https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr');
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION, CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "cmd=_notify-validate&".http_build_query($_POST));
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FORBID_REUSE, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Connection: Close'));

        if( !curl_errno($ch)) {
            $res = curl_exec($ch);
            curl_close($ch);
            if ($res === "VERIFIED") {
                return TRUE;
            }
        }

        return FALSE;
    }


    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST' && !empty($_POST)) {
        if(validateIpnMessage()) {
            // THE MESSAGE IS VALIDATED

            // REST OF YOUR CODE GOES HERE
        }
    }
?>
```

Did you make sure you have IPN enabled in your profile?
Anyway I advise you first check that your listener URL works by manually testing it
with the IPN test tool (available under 'test tools' in your account at [PayPal Sandbox](https://developer.paypal.com)

Comment: Yes, I see that you added it. But did you checked manually that your URL works. You can easily do that with a tool within the sandbox account , it is under the 'test tools' link on the menu on the left. Check it out.

Comment: I'm using sandbox account. And i have added notify_url in paypal form. So, i think no need for enabling IPN in profile. I have tested the notify url manually. It's working. As your advice, i have tested with IPN test tool. But i'm getting this error. "IPN delivery failed. Unable to connect to the specified URL. Please verify the URL and try again."\

Comment: well something is not right with your listener script.if can you post the code here it would help a lot to find the problem.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Nothing in listener script. I just sent a mail in that url. Can you please check paypal's sandbox - listerner url is either working or not.

Comment: Can anyone please check this in sandbox? This problem was occurred recently. I have received response for the first 5 to 6 payments. Thanks.

Comment: please give the full listener url i will ping it from my IPN test tool, but just for your information I believe that you have to post the received data back to PayPal first for validation, that's how it supposed to work. I you do not validate the data- PayPal considers the call to your listener failed.

Comment: Hi Guys, today i have checked with another site, which was already developed and tested with paypal sandbox. I found the problem, Paypal's sandbox is not sending a notification call to the specified url. Problem in Paypal's sandbox. Thanks.

Comment: Paypal's sandbox - notify_url call has not been working for past one week.